# How to save mysql query in a global array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express. I understand that the functions are executed asynchronously, but I don't get how to use global variables. Here I connect to mysql database, retrieve the query results and render them on my test.html page. Then in the mysql.js file, I want to save those results in an array called entry, so that the other get() can use those same results. The only alternative I can think of with my limited understanding of Node.js is to just query the database again in the other get(). How can I use this global to save my query results from the anonymous function? Also what event and function do I call so that I can execute my connection.end() correctly?

```js
//mysql.js
var express = require('./express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var hbs = require('./hbs');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db',
    port: 3306
});

connection.connect();

entry=[];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM table where ID < 10;',
    function(err, result, fields)
    {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('test',{title:"title", entries:result});
        entry = result;
    });
});

app.get('/article/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.render('article',{title:entry.title, blog:entry});
});

app.listen(3000);
//connection.end();
```

```html
<h1>HTML Test</h1>
{{#each entries}}
    <p>
        <a href="/article/{{ID}}">{{Name}}</a><br/>
        Name: {{Name}}
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to run a query to retrieve each article when it’s requested. Your first route (for `'/'`) looks fine. Just add a similar query for your second route:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=?', [req.params.id],
  function(err, rows, fields)
{
  if (err) { throw err; }
  if (!rows.length) { return res.send(404); }
  res.render('article', { title: rows[0].title, blog: rows[0] });
})
```

But if you really want to cache entries:

- Use [`redis`](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) or [`memcached`](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) if you want real caching. E.g. if you’re concerned about being slashdotted or whatever it’s called now. This needs a Redis or Memcache daemon and is a bit more involved.
- In your code, the SQL query doesn’t impose an ORDER. The only way to get an article with a particular ID is to loop over the global `entry` array looking at each one until you find the right one.
- Adding an `ORDER BY` clause doesn’t help because you could still skip an ID (or later delete an entry with a particular ID). You still have to loop over the entire array to find the one you want.

If you are done using the database, you can call `connection.end`. But if your app runs “forever” and you plan to access the DB from time to time, there’s no need to call it. The connection will be killed if/when your app is killed. A cleaner way is to let the `mysql` module manage connections for you. See the documentation section “[Pooling connections](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections)”.